# Placing menu circles above images on left and right of page

Tags: html, css

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family:'Baskerville', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', 'serif'
}

.homepage {
  background-image: url(pagepics/big_oscar.png), url(pagepics/emmy.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 220px, 220px;       
  padding: 250px;

}

.centeredImage {
  padding-left: 750px;  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 
}

h3 {
 font-size: 27.5px;
 color: cornflowerblue;
}

#header1{
 width:1220px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:125px;
 background-image:url(pagepics/oscars-banner3.jpg);
}

#header2{
 width:1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:100px;
 
 background-image:url(pagepics/emmybanner.png);
}

.indent {
    text-indent: 50px;
}

.link1 {
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #000;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#footer1 {
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}
   
img.floatLeft {
    float:left; 
    margin:5px;
 
}


#centerText1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: red; 
}

li h3 {
    margin: .1px 0;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.article:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: .3; 
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(pagepics/emmy.png);

}

.menu-container {
  text-align:center;
}

.ca-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 140px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.ca-menu li{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
 /*Circle Size*/
    border: 10px solid blue;
 /*border color before spin*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: red;
 /*background before spin*/
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
 /*circle vs square*/
    transition: all 1000ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
 /*text color before spin*/
    position:relative;
}

.ca-icon{
    font-size: 18px;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
    line-height: 135px;
    position: static;
 padding-left: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}

/*.ca-main{
    font-size: 15px;
 color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}*/
/*.ca-sub{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}*/

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: blue;
    border-color: red;
    transform: rotate(1440deg);
} /* colors after spin*/

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #BEFC00;
 font-size: 18px;
/*text size after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 8.0;
}

video {
 display:block;
 width: 30%; height: 30%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

table, th, td {
 color: cornflowerblue;
 margin:auto;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.th1 {
 color: white;
}

caption {
 font-size: 40px;color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

.table1 {
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:25px;
 padding: 40px;
    border:5px solid #D8FF01;
}


.button-3d {
  position:relative;
  width: auto;
  display:inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:solid 3px yellow;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
  padding:16px 18px 14px;
  margin: 12px;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px blue;
}

.button-3d:active{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px white;
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
}

.link {
 font-size: 30px;
}

#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 145px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  margin: auto;
}

#div2 {
 margin:auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
} 
#div3 {
 margin:auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
}

#div4 {
 margin:auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
}

textarea.myTextBox {
  width: 40%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  resize: both;
}

.space {
 padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}

.font {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 27.5px;
 color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Oscar/Emmy Fan Page">
<meta name="author" content="Brad Anderson">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="keywords" content="Oscar, Emmy, Academy Awards, Awards Show, statuette, Movies, Television, TV">

<title>Oscar/Emmy Information Home Page</title>

<link href="AndersonBradCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body class="homepage">

<div class="menu-container">
 
<header>
  
<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="AndersonBradHomePage.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Trivia</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="EmmyTrivia.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Trivia</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="OscarWinners.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Winners</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="EmmyWinners.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Winners</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>
 </ul> 

<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="PretendBestPicture.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Best Picture???</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>                                                                                                                 </ul>
 
<ul class="ca-menu">
 <li>
  <a href="EmmyChange.html" target="_blank">
            <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Change Emmys</strong></span>
           </a>
 </li>                                                                                                                 </ul> 

</header> 

<h5 id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Admittedly stumping me is not hard to do, but this one is a doozy, at least for me anyway.  What I want to do is place the menu circles I have created above the images on each side of the page.  I tried placing them within header tags, but that didn't work either.  Overall, I will need to add at least one more circle to the 7 I have already.  I can resize the circles/text as needed, but I do want them to overlap slightly.  I believe I have included all needed code.  I would prefer to keep this within the realm of HTML if at all possible.

```
<body class="homepage">

<div class="menu-container">

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="AndersonBradHomePage.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="OscarTrivia.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Trivia</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="EmmyTrivia.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Trivia</strong></span>
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="OscarWinners.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Oscar Winners</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="EmmyWinners.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Emmy Winners</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>   

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="PretendBestPicture.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Best Picture???</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="EmmyChange.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="ca-icon"><strong>Change Emmys</strong></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>   


<h5 id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</div>

.homepage {
    background-image: url(pagepics/big_oscar.png), url(pagepics/emmy.png);
    background-position: left, right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 220px, 220px;       
    padding: 250px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 27.5px;
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

li h3 {
    margin: .1px 0;
}

.menu-container {
    text-align:center;
}

.ca-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 140px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.ca-menu li{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    /*Circle Size*/
    border: 10px solid blue;
    /*border color before spin*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: red;
    /*background before spin*/
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    /*circle vs square*/
    transition: all 1000ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    /*text color before spin*/
    position:relative;
}

.ca-icon{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
    line-height: 135px;
    position: static;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: blue;
    border-color: red;
    transform: rotate(1440deg);
} /* colors after spin*/

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #BEFC00;
    font-size: 18px;
    /*text size after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 8.0;
}
```

Comment: An image of the desiyred result would be useful here

Comment: I can only run some of your code.
Please create a working snippet to share.

I assume you are looking for stacking elements/images on top of each other, but not totally covering. You can use CSS "z-index" for that.

Comment: @Toolbox I added the code snippet.  For both HTML and CSS, I included everything instead of editing out what I thought would not be needed

Comment: You need to define "image". Trying the snippet I see a circle (blue background, red center). When hovering the circle changes colors(red background, blue center) and the text spins around.

Is your aim to add an image? Or replace the circle with an image. 
Could you upload an image done in an image editor together with your layout so we see what you want the end-result to look like?